# Hibernate 4.0 Logical Expression or condition through all of a class' properties

Tags: hibernate

I have a project that I have to implement a lazy sort of search on database.

What I'd like to do is to use org.hibernate.criterion.Example but using 'or' condition for
each property.

For example, let's say I have a class like below

```
public class Cat{
   private String name;
   private String breed;
   private Date birthDay;
/*getter and setter omitted*/
}
```

And I set all three of the fields with some value

```
Cat cat2Find = new Cat();
cat2Find.setName("Nabi");
cat2Find.setBreed("That hairless Egyptian cat");
cat2Find.setBirthDay( someDate );    //5th May 2005 for example
```

I want to find a cat 
whose name is "Nabi" 
or breed is "hairless Egyptian cat"
or whose birthday is 5th May 2005

I tried using org.hibernate.criterion.Example but show_sql showed me it used And condition for each fields.
I also tried using org.hibernate.criterion.Disjunction with LogicalExpression 
but it was so cumbersome to iterate through all the fields.

I wonder if there is some class that works like criterion.Example but with and condition for
each fields or I can choose either 'And' or 'OR'.

Thank you for your time : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    // Use disjunction() or conjunction() if you need more than 2 expressions
Disjunction aOrBOrC = Restrictions.disjunction(); // A or B or C
aOrBOrC.add(Restrictions.eq("b", "a"));
aOrBOrC.add(Restrictions.eq("b", "b"));
aOrBOrC.add(Restrictions.eq("b", "c"));

// Use Restrictions.and() / or() if you only have 2 expressions
crit.add(Restrictions.and(Restrictions.eq("a", "abc"), aOrBOrC));
```

this way u can make simple query with "AND"/"OR".

Comment: thanks but is there a way I can do this without adding a restriction for each property in my bean? just like criteron.Example ?